# Entity Framework Core Generic Get with Include and Filter/Search

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an EF Core model for tracking employee training.  There is an `Employee` entity/SQL table, a `Training` entity/SQL table, and an `EmployeeTraining` entity/SQL table that joins the two for the many-to-many relationship.

Every `Employee` and `Training` has a unique GUID id.

I have the following generic method that get all objects that is working as expected:

```cs
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<T> queryable = GetAll();
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Include<T, object>(includeProperty);
    }

    return queryable;
}
```

I can use this generic function to get all `Employees` and their associated `Trainings`:

`IQueryable<Training> = GetAllIncluding(e => e.EmployeeTrainings);`

or get all `Trainings` and their associated `Employees` like so:

`IQueryable<Employee> = GetAllIncluding(e => e.EmployeeTrainings);`

I can't figure out how to implement a generic method that finds and returns ONE object by its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define an interface similar to this:

```cs
public interface IUniquelyIdentifiable
{
   Guid Id {get; set;}
}
```

2. Modify your `Employee` and `Training` entities to implement this interface
3. Introduce the following method

```cs
public virtual T GetAllIncluding<T>(Guid id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    where T : class, IUniquelyIdentifiable

{
    IQueryable<T> queryable = GetAll();
    foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Include<T, object>(includeProperty);
    }

    return queryable.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: The function (step 3) is giving a compiler error - "Constraints are not allowed on non-generic functions."  I tried changing GetAllIncluding to GetAllIncluding<T>,  which fixes the compiler error for the function declaration, but then the function code itself starts throwing other compiler errors.  I've tried variations of <T> with no success.

Comment: @ScotWoodyard Quite frankly I did not put my code into an IDE, that's why there was a couple of syntax errors. Sorry for that. I've updated my post, now it should compile.